# How to send Image file from Ionic 2 File Transfer Plugin to Openbravo Web Service

Tags: java, http-post, ionic2, openbravo

I have to send Image from Ionic 2 mobile app to Openbravo web service and there I have to save that Image into server.
My Ionic 2 Code:

[image]

My Web Service doPost Code in Java:
[image]

How I can extract request data in doPost request and that Image File in java ?

Comment: did you check in postman? what you are getting